# How to run the HTTP request without using CURL

Tags: wget, busybox

I have ARM cpu based BusyBox v1.8.1 (Embedded Linux) with limited binaries. How can I http post or put without using curl? I have wget available:

```
# wget
BusyBox v1.8.1 (2015-04-06 16:22:12 IDT) multi-call binary

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document file]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-U|--user-agent agent] url

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

Options:
        -s      Spider mode - only check file existence
        -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q      Quiet
        -P      Set directory prefix to DIR
        -O      Save to filename ('-' for stdout)
        -U      Adjust 'User-Agent' field
        -Y      Use proxy ('on' or 'off')
```

CPU info...

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 1 (v5l)
```

Comment: --post-data= or --post-file= is what you are looking for, the thing is that since that `wget` is part of the Busybox I don't know if it has all the capabilities or it is a simplified `wge`t and doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A lot depends on what you have in your busybox and other commands. I don't
think your limited `wget` can be used; however, a *simple* POST request can
be emulated with just a `cat`, provided you can open a socket, e.g. with `nc`
(netcat, socat), `telnet`, or even with a full version of `bash`, as it can
do a connect, as shown below:

On another machine, use `curl` to do the request, and copy all the data it
writes. Eg:

```
curl --trace-ascii - -0 -d var=val http://localhost/~meuh/dump.cgi
```

This shows in the curl trace output that it sent:

```
POST /~meuh/dump.cgi HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

var=val
```

If you put this in a file, you can reproduce the POST, e.g. to google with
the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
cat mypostfile >&5
cat <&5 # reply
```

This probably only works well for smallish data, and servers that aren't
too fussy with `\r\n` line endings, but may suffice for you.

Comment: Fantastic, what is that '5' in bash script ?

Comment: it's just a new file descriptor. I could have re-used the usual 1 for stdout, but it's better to open the tcp port for input and output (<>) into a new fd, so we can be explicit when doing i/o with the socket.

Comment: brilliantly done

Comment: how to make a get?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic You should probably post a new question specific to your needs, but if you follow the same technique you end up with a file where the word `POST` is replaced by `GET`, and you only need the first 4 lines followed by a blank line (i.e. no `Content-Length`, no `Content-Type`, no `var=val`).

Answer (score 1):

Many tools can be statically compiled (I know it for sure with `netcat`) inside Buildroot (http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and then downloaded using `wget` onto the device. That's what I did in a similar situation.

Just care to set the correct options, you can access them using `make menuconfig`. The following option pages will probably be the most important ones for you (I marked the often important options using with `!>`):

- Target

```
  │ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
!>│ │        Target Architecture (FOOBAR)  --->                                  │ │  
  │ │        Target Binary Format (ELF)  --->                                    │ │  
!>│ │        Target Architecture Variant (Gen42)  --->                           │ │  
  │ │        Target ABI (EABI)  --->                                             │ │  
  │ │        Floating point strategy (Soft float)  --->                          │ │  
  │ │                                                                            │ │
```

- Build Options

```
!>│ │        libraries (static only)  --->                                       │ │  
  │ │    ($(CONFIG_DIR)/local.mk) location of a package override file            │ │  
  │ │    ()  global patch directories                                            │ │  
  │ │        Advanced  --->                                                      │ │  
  │ └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

- Toolchain

```
  │ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
  │ │        Toolchain type (Buildroot toolchain)  --->                          │ │  
  │ │    (buildroot) custom toolchain vendor name                                │ │  
  │ │        *** Kernel Header Options ***                                       │ │  
!>│ │        Kernel Headers (Manually specified Linux version)  --->             │ │  
!>│ │    (2.6.99) linux version                                                  │ │  
!>│ │        Custom kernel headers series (2.6.x)  --->                          │ │  
  │ │        C library (uClibc)  --->                                            │ │  
  │ │        *** uClibc Options ***                                              │ │  
!>│ │        uClibc C library Version (uClibc 0.9.33.x)  --->                    │ │
```

Then build the toolchain using `make toolchain` and then what tool you need, e.g. `make nc`.